# How to access samba share on super network?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, samba

I have 3 layers of networks at home.

192.168.2.XXX is part of 192.168.1.XXX.
192.168.1.XXX is part of 192.168.0.XXX.

My samba server is placed on the 192.168.0.XXX network.

When using ES File Explorer on my phone to browse the LAN, the server is found regardless of the network I'm logged on to. On my computer (Lubuntu 14.04) it only seems to search within the current network, so unless I specifically connect to the 192.168.0.XXX network it can't be found by going to PCManFM > Go > Network > Windows Network. How can I make Windows Network search for super networks as well?